# Why is the unary minus operator problematic in this expression: (- 2) 1?

Tags: haskell, infix-operator

All of the following expressions get evaluated without mishap:

```hs
(+2) 1 -- 3
(*2) 1 -- 2
((-)2) 1 -- 1
(2-) 1 -- 1   
(/2) 1 -- 0.5
(2/) 1 -- 2.0
```

but not this one:

```hs
(-2) 1 -- the inferred type is ambiguous
```

GHC throws some error about the inferred type being ambiguous. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first six parenthesised expressions are *sections*, i.e. functions that take one argument and "put it on the missing side of the infix operator" (see this [haskell.org wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator)). In contrast, `(-2)` is, not a *function*, but a *number* (negative 2):

```
λ> :t (-2)
(-2) :: Num a => a
```

If you write

```
λ> (-2) 1
```

it looks like you're trying to apply `(-2)` (a number) to `1` (which is not possible), and GHCi rightfully complains:

```
Could not deduce (Num (a0 -> t))
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘it’
from the context (Num (a -> t), Num a)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘it’: (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t
  at <interactive>:3:1-6
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
When checking that ‘it’
  has the inferred type ‘forall a t. (Num (a -> t), Num a) => t’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
```

If you want a function that subtracts `2` from another number, you can use

```
(subtract 2)
```

Compare its type,

```
λ> :t (subtract 2)
(subtract 2) :: Num a => a -> a
```

to that of `(-2)` (see above).

---

#### Terminology addendum (after OP's edit)

Parenthesizing the minus operator turns it into a normal (prefix) function that takes two arguments; therefore `((-) 2)` is not a section, but a partially applied function.

Comment: Oh, I was initially confused with `LiveScript`, where `(-1)` is number while `(- 1)` is partial function.

Comment: @sof Whitespace doesn't matter, in this case.

Comment: Yes, I see `Haskell` is usually whitespace insensitive except for indented code block.

Comment: Also you could add that `(/ 2)` is `\x->x/2` and `((/) 2)` is `\x->2/x`

Comment: @KarolS That should be understood based on the first sentence in my answer.